# htaccess: Redirect All domains (https and http) to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, directadmin

My current domain is a free https.

I add new domains as parked domains Alias (in DirectAdmin).

So for the new domain to use https, I need to disable https for the old domains.

Now I want to transfer all the old domains to the new domain with https.

I think the solution is that https should be disabled for all domains except the new domain, then the address will be transferred to the new domain

Answer (score 2):

You can force https like so:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

That should go to your .htaccess to your root folder

source: https://www.siteground.com/kb/how-to-force-ssl-with-htaccess/

Comment: I do not want a forced https.

I want https to be disabled for all domains except the new domain.
Also, all domains will be transferred to the new domain

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?newdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect all parked domains (pointing to your document root) to your new domain url .

The `RewriteCondition` above makes sure you don't redirect `newdoman` to itself otherwise the rule would cause a redirect loop error.

Comment: This code does not pass `https://oldDomain.com` to the new domain.
Because the error appears in the browser: **Your connection is not private.**
I think the solution is that https should be disabled for all domains except the new domain, then the address will be transferred to the new domain.

Comment: @Mohammad you need to install valid ssl certs for your domains in order to redirect them.

Comment: There are codes for transmitting https to http. I just want the code to change so that it does not include the new domain

Comment: @mohammad if ssl cert doesn't exist for the domain your are trying to redirect from `https` to `http` then there is nothing htaccess redirect can do in that case you would need to buy a valid cert and install on the domain. You are getting `connection not private` error from the ssl module as your domain doesn't have ssl installed .